# Error installing psycopg2 on Manjaro OS in order to use postgresql in django

Tags: django, postgresql, psycopg2

i'm in manjaro.
I just migrated from mysql to postgresql.
After much difficulty installing postgresql i get error :(
the final result when in want install psycopg2:

```
pip install psycopg2
```

the Result is:

```
Collecting psycopg2
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/84/d7/6a93c99b5ba4d4d22daa3928b983cec66df4536ca50b22ce5dcac65e4e71/psycopg2-2.8.4.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: psycopg2
  Building wheel for psycopg2 (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/nima/project/django/coders/env/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-bc661h33/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-bc661h33/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-w4_ngmz0 --python-tag cp36
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-bc661h33/psycopg2/
  Complete output (36 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psycopg2
  copying lib/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psycopg2
  copying lib/errors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psycopg2
  copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psycopg2
  copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psycopg2
  copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psycopg2
  copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psycopg2
  copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psycopg2
  copying lib/_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psycopg2
  copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psycopg2
  copying lib/_lru_cache.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psycopg2
  copying lib/sql.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psycopg2
  copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psycopg2
  copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psycopg2
  running build_ext
  building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/psycopg
  x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -pipe -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -pipe -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/home/nima/anaconda3/include/python3.6m -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
  unable to execute 'x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc': No such file or directory

  It appears you are missing some prerequisite to build the package from source.

  You may install a binary package by installing 'psycopg2-binary' from PyPI.
  If you want to install psycopg2 from source, please install the packages
  required for the build and try again.

  For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
  <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html>).

  error: command 'x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for psycopg2
  Running setup.py clean for psycopg2
Failed to build psycopg2
Installing collected packages: psycopg2
    Running setup.py install for psycopg2 ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/nima/project/django/coders/env/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-bc661h33/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-bc661h33/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-hkcgaxlg/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/nima/project/django/coders/env/include/site/python3.6/psycopg2
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-bc661h33/psycopg2/
    Complete output (36 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psycopg2
    copying lib/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psycopg2
    copying lib/errors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psycopg2
    copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psycopg2
    copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psycopg2
    copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psycopg2
    copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psycopg2
    copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psycopg2
    copying lib/_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psycopg2
    copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psycopg2
    copying lib/_lru_cache.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psycopg2
    copying lib/sql.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psycopg2
    copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psycopg2
    copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/psycopg2
    running build_ext
    building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/psycopg
    x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -pipe -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -pipe -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/home/nima/anaconda3/include/python3.6m -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    unable to execute 'x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc': No such file or directory

    It appears you are missing some prerequisite to build the package from source.

    You may install a binary package by installing 'psycopg2-binary' from PyPI.
    If you want to install psycopg2 from source, please install the packages
    required for the build and try again.

    For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
    <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html>).

    error: command 'x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/nima/project/django/coders/env/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-bc661h33/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-bc661h33/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-hkcgaxlg/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/nima/project/django/coders/env/include/site/python3.6/psycopg2 Check the logs for full command output.
```

What i todo for install it?!

djang versin:3
os:manjaro
postgresql from aur (last version)

can i use postgres without psycopg2????

Comment: Did you try installing with `pip install psycopg2-binary`?

Comment: You need to install build-essential (gcc is part of it) on your system. On a Debian/Ubuntu system you'd do that with `sudo apt-get install build-essential` but I never heard of manjaro.

Comment: i am in manjaro.its use pacman and pacman do'ent have build-essential

Comment: its worked.thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in the error you showed us:

> You may install a binary package by installing 'psycopg2-binary' from PyPI.
>       If you want to install psycopg2 from source, please install the packages
>       required for the build and try again.

So either try `pip install psycopg2-binary` or make sure you've installed `gcc` before installing from source.

Note that even after you install `gcc` there will probably be other errors, in which case you'll need to install these missing packages as well until there are no errors anymore. On common Linux distributions, you'll find the `build-essential` package that includes most common packages for building other packages. On Manjaro/Arch linux, this is the `base-devel` package.